# Disable error message: `error: The branch 'stack' is not fully merged.`

Tags: git

I had rebased my commits and merged `stack` branch into current one.

```
< e6c8324 (HEAD -> bot) Add '/' to url in API::Redmine
<   4c785be Merge branch 'stack' into bot
|\  
| = b52b42c Reconfigure stack Put Bot into office-net network. Thus we can remove own tra>
| = b0149ff Tune application on production differently
| = 3a308b9 Changed redmine files path to /db
|/  
< 21c0f91 Fix fatal error which to cause by sending edit message
< 07c50ba Fix list commands and aliases
< 41c5825 Provide aliases
< 4dc5ae6 Unnecessary commented code deleted
| = 4e6e52a (stack) Reconfigure stack Put Bot into office-net network. Thus we can remove>
| = ed7bc5b Tune application on production differently
| = bfd958e Changed redmine files path to /db
|/  
o 798fd89 Merge branch 'clean-up-stack-bulding' into bot
```

When I try to delete that `stack` branch, I get error:

```
$ git branch -d stack
error: The branch 'stack' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D stack'.
```

**Is there a way to silence error message in my case**: when commits has different IDs, but are similar and merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your `git log` output, commit `4e6e52a` is indeed *not* merged into the current `bot` branch (commit `e6c8324`), so Git's complaint here is correct.  But as you note in the body of the question, the commits that *are* merged (e.g., `b52b42c`) are patch-ID-equivalent to the commits that aren't merged.

Git's `git branch -d` *does not* detect this case (and never has done so), so you must do your own detection and invoke a force-delete (`git branch --force -d` or `git branch -D`) to force `git branch` to delete without complaining.

Comment: But even when the very _same_ commit as your branch tip has been merged, if there is no _local_ branch that it was merged into (because the merge took place thru a pull request), Git complains when you delete the branch. This is what I was saying in my now deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086710/can-git-branch-d-be-smarter-about-the-fact-that-this-branch-is-actually-merge. Git is just not very smart about whether it is safe to delete a branch. So I basically _always_ have to force delete my feature branches.

Comment: @matt: I agree: there's something generally deficient here, although what it is in detail I think needs the equivalent of Mercurial's "evolve" extension to solve properly.

Comment: Ok. As I can see there is no such option. `git` should be smarter at this place. Would be nice if this command will have `--detect` option, which will `detect` that all commits are merged.